# When trying to run a script to test whether tensorflow is installed I get a massive error that I do not understand

Tags: python, tensorflow, random

I have a script to try and test tensorflow's installation as seen here:

```
import tensorflow
```

And get a massive error that also includes an error to do with random in it.

```
  File "tensorflowtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 187, in <module>
    from .testing import Tester
  File "C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._private.utils import *
  File "C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tempfile import mkdtemp, mkstemp
  File "C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "C:\Users\jiney\Desktop\random.py", line 2, in <module>
    print (random.randint(16, 17))
AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randint'
```

I genuinely have no idea what any of this means, or how to fix it, or what it means.

Answer (score 0):

You have a module named `random.py` on your desktop. It is imported instead of the built-in module `random`. Rename that module, or run your code in a different working directory.